# Commit unstaged deleted files

Tags: git, git-commit, git-push

I have lost some of my local files, but I still have them in my unpushed "commit". When I try to "git push" them, "Writing objects" is stuck on 20%.

From what I have seen, my commit is perhaps too big to be pushed and `http.postBuffer` didn't fix it, so I was thinking of splitting my commit into several parts.

I have tried the `git rebase -i master` command, but I get the `Cannot rebase: You have unstaged changes.` message.

Since my files are deleted, I can't really do a 'commit' since it will overwrite the existing files in my commit with the deleted ones. Is there a way to push the files?

Comment: try stashing so that your tree gets cleaned up and then try to run the rebase. `git stash save "will come back in a few minutes"`

Comment: It may be that I don't fully understand the situation, but can you simply unstage your files? This should overwrite the working directory with the staged version of the files, overwriting the "deletion" that is currently in your working dir. (i.e. `git rm --cached` I think is the command line version of this)

Answer (score 1):

If you switch your remote to [use ssh](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh) the `http.postBuffer` problem might go away. `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:<org/user>/<repo>.git`.

---

To be able to rebase you need to clear your staging area.

You can [stash your unstaged changes](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Stashing-and-Cleaning) and retrieve them later.

Or you can commit them with a message like "WIP" (work in progress), rebase, and then "redo" the commit with `git reset --soft HEAD^`. This will remove the last commit and return its changes to your staging area.